# Performing multiple validations on one field C#

Tags: c#, validation, textbox

I have to validate the textboxes to check if they are a number and if they are in the database. Only problem is I can only seem to get it to check for validity or if they are numeric. How can change this to get both validations?

it validates to make sure there is something in the textboxes:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeIDTextBox.Text) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(JobIDTextBox.Text)))
```

Then it looks to see if the value is numeric, then if it does it checks to see if the person exists, then sets the values

```
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(JobIDTextBox.Text))
     {
        if (!Int32.TryParse(JobIDTextBox.Text, out number1))
        {
           using (dbConn)
           {
              ReportGrid newGrid = new ReportGrid();

              if (newGrid.isValidEmp(Int32TryParseSafe(employeeIDTextBox.Text)))
              {
                  newGrid.startDate = startingdateTimePicker.Value;
                  newGrid.endDate = endingdateTimePicker.Value;

                  newGrid.EmployeeID = Int32TryParseSafe(employeeIDTextBox.Text);
                  newGrid.JobID = Int32TryParseSafe(JobIDTextBox.Text);

                  newGrid.ShowDialog();
               }
               else
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("No ID found for the employee.", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
```

Then it does the same for the other textbox

```
else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeIDTextBox.Text))
      {
          if (!Int32.TryParse(emplyeeIDLabel.Text, out number2))
          {
             using (dbConn)
             {
                 ReportGrid newGrid = new ReportGrid();

                 if (newGrid.isValidJob(Int32TryParseSafe(JobIDTextBox.Text)))
                 {
                     newGrid.startDate = startingdateTimePicker.Value;
                     newGrid.endDate = endingdateTimePicker.Value;

                     newGrid.EmployeeID = Int32TryParseSafe(employeeIDTextBox.Text);
                     newGrid.JobID = Int32TryParseSafe(JobIDTextBox.Text);

                     newGrid.ShowDialog();
                   }

                   else
                   {
                      MessageBox.Show("No ID found for that job.", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                   }
                }
             }
             else
                MessageBox.Show("Must be a number.");
           }
```

Here is the whole code

```
try
{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeIDTextBox.Text) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(JobIDTextBox.Text)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a EmployeeID or JobID.", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
     }
     else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(JobIDTextBox.Text))
     {
        if (!Int32.TryParse(JobIDTextBox.Text, out number1))
        {
           using (dbConn)
           {
              ReportGrid newGrid = new ReportGrid();

              if (newGrid.isValidEmp(Int32TryParseSafe(employeeIDTextBox.Text)))
              {
                  newGrid.startDate = startingdateTimePicker.Value;
                  newGrid.endDate = endingdateTimePicker.Value;

                  newGrid.EmployeeID = Int32TryParseSafe(employeeIDTextBox.Text);
                  newGrid.JobID = Int32TryParseSafe(JobIDTextBox.Text);

                  newGrid.ShowDialog();
               }
               else
               {
                   MessageBox.Show("No ID found for the employee.", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }

             }
         }
         else
            MessageBox.Show("Must be a number.");

         if (startingdateTimePicker.Value > endingdateTimePicker.Value)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Starting data can not be after than ending date.", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
         }
      }
      else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeIDTextBox.Text))
      {
          if (!Int32.TryParse(emplyeeIDLabel.Text, out number2))
          {
             using (dbConn)
             {
                 ReportGrid newGrid = new ReportGrid();

                 if (newGrid.isValidJob(Int32TryParseSafe(JobIDTextBox.Text)))
                 {
                     newGrid.startDate = startingdateTimePicker.Value;
                     newGrid.endDate = endingdateTimePicker.Value;

                     newGrid.EmployeeID = Int32TryParseSafe(employeeIDTextBox.Text);
                     newGrid.JobID = Int32TryParseSafe(JobIDTextBox.Text);

                     newGrid.ShowDialog();
                   }

                   else
                   {
                      MessageBox.Show("No ID found for that job.", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                   }
                }
             }
             else
                MessageBox.Show("Must be a number.");
           }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: How are you checking to see if they are in the database?

Comment: I would recommend pulling your two bottom else if's into their own functions that could return a bool. Then you could call one after the other without messing with all of those else if's.

Comment: @N4TKD a called method in my other class

Comment: @DROPtableusers so make a method that can work for both validations?

Comment: Ok then what does that code look like, and what problem are you having with it? We need to see how you are calling to the database and how you are checking to see if the database has the value already.

Comment: @N4TKD that's not the issue it works perfectly it's way I'm using my if statements.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos two different functions would be fine.  You just want to isolate some of the functionality to clean up some of this checking and rechecking values.

Comment: OK will I would reverse your thinking, instead of if the text is empty do something reverse it to if the text box is not empty do stuff. It will simplify the code for you. By the way what do you want to happen if both boxes have values?

Comment: @N4TKD that is what I'm working on now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be mistaken but is this line possibly the problem?

```
if (!Int32.TryParse(emplyeeIDLabel.Text, out number2))
```

The exclamation point reverses the bool so if the text successfully parses as a number the TryParse function returns true but by using the exclamation the if statement resolves to false. Therefore you are sending the code to else statement which states that it is not a number.

Also, try using "Return" to avoid nested ifs.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeeIDTextBox.Text) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(JobIDTextBox.Text)))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a EmployeeID or JobID.", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    Return;
 }
```

There's no need for an else at this point because the if the if statement resolves to true you will return from the method.

Nested if statements are frequently necessary but they should be avoided when they can to make code clearer to read for maintenance.